# Deriving $f(x)=c_1 \sin (A x) + c_2 \cos (A x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to derive $$f(x)=c_1 \sin (A x) + c_2 \cos (A x)$$ from $$f(x)=c_1 e^{-A x} + c_2 e^{A x}$$ when $A<0$? I thought it is the application of Euler's formula but where did the $i$ go?

Comment: Not possible. RHS of the first equation is bounded, that of the second equation is tends to $\infty$ as $ x \to -\infty$.

Comment: You need A purely complex and the $c_1$ and $c_2$ in the two forms are not the same. You could write the first form in terms of $sinh$ and $cosh$ if A is real. The restriction $A<0$ is not required.

Comment: This appears similar to the possible transmission error in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4533036/how-to-convert-exponential-function-to-trigonometric-function

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean $\cosh(Ax)$ and $\sinh(Ax)$, no? $\{\sinh(Ax),\cosh(Ax)\}$ and $\{e^{Ax},e^{-Ax}\}$ are both bases of the solution space for the ODE $y''-A^2y=0$, so their spans are equal.

By the way, it's best not to reuse the names $c_1$ and $c_2$ for the constants in the second equation, since they are not the same as the ones in the first equation.

Comment: This seems to be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: As far as I can tell it answers the question; the question was asking how to show that the spans of these two sets of functions are equal. The theorem that a 2nd order linear ODE has a 2-dimensional solution space proves this.

Comment: I don't think so. I found an example from [this page](https://web1.eng.famu.fsu.edu/~dommelen/pdes/style_a/svcex.html) (see case λ not equal 0)